# Saving a reference to an image in camera roll to recall later in app?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to let the user take or select an image in an `ImagePickerController`, and I want to save a reference (as efficiently as possible) in my app to recall when the app loads again.  Is saving the image's file URL the best approach for this?

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary
    
    @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return imagePicker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        
        var parent: ImagePicker
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            
            if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.selectedImage = image
            }
            
            if let imgUrl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? URL{
                let imgName = imgUrl.lastPathComponent
                let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
                let localPath = documentDirectory?.appending(imgName)
                
                let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
                let data = image.pngData()! as NSData
                data.write(toFile: localPath!, atomically: true)
                //let imageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: localPath!)!
                let photoURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: localPath!)//NSURL(fileURLWithPath: localPath!)
                print(photoURL)
                //TODO save this url in my app as a reference to look up
                
            }
            
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that URL may change , better way is to save your image to filesystem in the app sandbox and the you can save given name or something to retrieve it when u needed back !

Comment: @Yodagama thanks, can you point me to some sample code on saving to the filesystem in the app sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL of image of camera roll may change , better way is to save your image to filesystem in the app sandbox and the you can save given name or something to retrieve it when u needed back

```swift
//MARK: save and retrive Images
extension UIImage {
    func saveImage(imageName: String) {
        
        guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
        
        let fileName = imageName
        let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        guard let data = self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) else { return }
        
        //Checks if file exists, removes it if so.
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: fileURL.path)
                print("Removed old image")
            } catch let removeError {
                print("couldn't remove file at path", removeError)
            }
        }
        do {
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
        } catch let error {
            print("error saving file with error", error)
        }
        
    }
    
    static func loadImageFromDiskWith(fileName: String) -> UIImage? {
        
        let documentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
        
        let userDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(documentDirectory, userDomainMask, true)
        
        if let dirPath = paths.first {
            let imageUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
            let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageUrl.path)
            return image
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    static func removeImage(fileName: String){
        
        guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
        
        let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: fileURL.path)
                print("Removed image")
            } catch let removeError {
                print("couldn't remove file at path", removeError)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Usage

```
yourImage.saveImage(imageName: "imageNameToSave")//<-save
UIImage.loadImageFromDiskWith(fileName: "ImageNameToRetrive")//<-retrive
UIImage.removeImage(fileName: "ImageNameToRemove")//<-remove
```

Comment: Does this also save the image into camera roll?

Comment: no Image u select from camera roll, will be saved in the fileSystem? so then, even the user delet the image from camera roll the image will be there in the filesystem.

Comment: Great!  If they get a new iPhone it will be lost though correct?  Any way to persist using iCloud maybe? 

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH12-SW51

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
You can definitely do `FileManager` as well, it truly depends on how many files you will be saving, and to where you want to save them. If it is a measly 1 file, that doesn't need to be secured and is public to the app, `UserDefaults` is the way to go. If you want to add a bit more control of that file, `FileManager` would be the way to go.

`UserDefaults` is your way to go to store locally.

Store Image Data

```
func locallyStoreImgData(image: UIImage, key:String) {
    if let pngRepresentation = image.pngData() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(pngRepresentation, forKey: key)
    }
    else {
        //Was unable to create png representation
    }
}
```

Retrieve Image Data

```
func obtainImg(key:String) -> UIImage? {
    if let imageData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? Data, 
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
        return image
    }
    return nil
}
```

Use Case

```
locallyStoreImgData(image: myImage, key: "myImageKey")

if let image = obtainImg(key: "myImageKey") {
    //Do something with image
}
else {
    //Was unable to recreate image
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is a fitness app that I was looking to let the user associate 1 image per workout.

Comment: Ahh, it may be more efficient to use the File Manager if you are saving that many files. Something quick and easy is what the UserDefaults is for